# can I install javacard development kit on eclipse 4.2 within the android bundle?

Tags: eclipse, javacard

I have seen some content online about using Eclipse 3.2 with javacard development. I am wondering if anyone has used Eclipse 4.2 to develop and run javacard applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any Eclipse version for JavaCard development, some parts of the overall debugging and deployment stages just need manual intervention. See [AppletPlayground](https://github.com/martinpaljak/AppletPlayground) for a quickstarter with Eclipse.

The NXP JCOP environment is also compatible with most Eclipse versions, by now you may find Eclipse SDK's from other vendors as well.

Comment: I should have mentioned that, for now, I am on a windows machine. I looked online; everything I see calls for Eclipse 3.2. If you known of a specific SDK, that supports this I would really appreciate it. i have been searching for this for a while now.

Comment: Eclipse versions are largely backwards compatible. That something states 3.2 does not mean that it does not run on 4.2. 4.2 is a separate branch that does some fundamental things differently than 3, but that does not mean that everything is suddenly incompatible. So try out the plugin and see if it works, but keep a backup of your project for 3.2.